# WPF Metro design: How apply character case with Style?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to develop a UI in **WPF** following Metro design principles - see Scott Barnes [website](http://www.riagenic.com/archives/487) for a great survey. 
**Character casing** is one of Metro milestone, which can be easily achieved in **css** using **text-transform** property. 
What about WPF control? 
It would be useful to declare various style for menu, title, subtitle in a resource file, and modify casing by simply editing the applied style.

Note:

[1] TextBox.CharacterCasing doesn't apply, it involves only manually entered characters.

[2] I can't imagine an appropriate value converter for this task.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple approaches to this.  On a per-case basis you may want all upper or lower case characters.  You can easily apply a ValueConverter which will apply logic and return a value.

Quick example of this type of implementation:

```
<converters:LowerCase x:Key="toLowerConverter"/>

<ControlTemplate TargetType="CustomControlYouMade">
   <HeaderedContentControl Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type CustomControlYouMade}}, Path=Header, Converter={StaticResource toLowerConverter}}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

And the converter logic:

```
public sealed class LowerCase : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var str = value as string;
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? string.Empty : str.ToLower();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {}
}
```

---

For advanced typography options like ligatures, subscript/superscript, swashes, etcetera., you'll need a compatible OpenType font.  See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745109.aspx) to see what's possible.